# Flexbox adding columns + rows within the same flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So I am trying to create a layout that has a sidebar, and then to the right of that there are four more elements, but how do I have one item flex-direction: row and the others columns, is there a way to mix these or is that bad practice?

```
<header>
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1813/5651/t/28/assets/logo.png?37614">
  </div>
  <div class="nav">
    <a href="">Link</a>
    <a href="">Link</a>
    <a href="">Link</a>
    <a href="">Link</a>
    <a href="">Link</a>
  </div>
  <div class="settings">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50.png/">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50.png/">
  </div>
</header>

<div class="content">
  <div class="sideBar">
    <h1>Sidebar</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="patientCard">
    <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis, saepe animi quisquam maxime, voluptatibus optio natus debitis ipsum delectus eveniet fugiat? Quas sed magnam consectetur accusantium sequi! Sequi, nobis ut!</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="videoCard">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia odit, quam doloremque dolor praesentium fuga dignissimos. Vero quod necessitatibus ex consequatur laudantium, nemo, voluptate hic, optio autem incidunt sit quisquam.</p>
  </div>


body, h1 {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
header {
  display: flex;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, #3387FE, #3387FE);
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 30px rgba(107, 146, 173, 0.2);
  align-items: center;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 0px 20px;
  .logo {
    flex: 1;
    img {
      width: 50px;
    }
  }
  .nav {
    a {
      font-size: 24px;
      color: #fff;
      margin: 0px 5px;
      text-decoration: none;
      border-bottom: 3px solid #fff;
    }
  }
  .settings {
    flex: 1;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    display: flex;
    img {
      border-radius: 50%;
      height: 50%;
      margin-left: 10px;
    }
  }
}

.sideBar {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #313131;
  width: 30%;
  h1 {
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
  }
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  .patientCard {
    background-color: #ddd;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    margin: 30px;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 20%;
    border-radius: 3px;
  }
  .videoCard {

  }
}
```

Here is the link to the pen: https://codepen.io/jacksonrose/pen/MWWQRqo

This is what I am trying to achieve

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use **flex-child** as a **flex-container** to meet your needs.
From the illustration of the picture you gave, I made a simple example

```css
.header {
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}

.container .sidebar {
  border: 1px solid red;
  flex: 1;
}

.container .content {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 1px solid red;
  flex: 3;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.container .content .card {
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
}

.container .content .content-grid {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}

.content-grid__aside {
  flex: 1;
}

.content-grid__column {
  flex: 2;
}

.card-1 {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.card-2 {
  height: 100%;
  margin-right: .5rem;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <h1>Header</h1>
</header>
<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar">
    Sidebar
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="card card-1">Card 1</div>
    <div class="content-grid">
      <div class="content-grid__aside">
        <div class="card card-2">Card 2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="content-grid__column">
        <div class="card card-3">Card 3</div>
        <div class="card card-4">Card 4</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Everything is just about the algorithm you made and using the right flexbox property. 
 If you want using Flexbox